# <Error xsi:type="xsd:string">Unexpected Error has occured.</Error>

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I am getting this error and not receiving output. Can you please help me out?

```
<Messages>
              <Status>-999</Status>
              <Errors>
                 <Error xsi:type="xsd:string">Unexpected Error has occured </Error>
              </Errors>
              <Warnings/>
           </Messages>
```

Here is the complete code:
**Sent**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:echo="http://www.echo.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <echo:GetQuote>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <echo:echoRateRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <echo:AuthInfo>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <echo:UserId></echo:UserId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <echo:Password></echo:Password>
            </echo:AuthInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <echo:Requests>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <echo:Request>
                  <echo:TotalWeight>1000</echo:TotalWeight>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <echo:Items>
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <echo:Item OriginId="1" DestinationId="1">
                        <echo:Class>70</echo:Class>
                        <echo:Weight>1000</echo:Weight>
                     </echo:Item>
                  </echo:Items>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <echo:Accessorials>
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <echo:Accessorial>
                        <echo:AccessorialId>12</echo:AccessorialId>
                        <echo:Charge>0</echo:Charge>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <echo:PickDel></echo:PickDel>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <echo:RateType></echo:RateType>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <echo:Description>?</echo:Description>
                     </echo:Accessorial>
                  </echo:Accessorials>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <echo:Origin Id="">
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Name></echo:Name>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Address1></echo:Address1>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Address2></echo:Address2>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:City></echo:City>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:State></echo:State>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Zip>91101</echo:Zip>
                  </echo:Origin>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <echo:Destination Id="?">
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Name></echo:Name>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Address1></echo:Address1>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Address2></echo:Address2>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:City></echo:City>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:State></echo:State>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <echo:Zip>60425</echo:Zip>
                  </echo:Destination>
                  <echo:PickupDate>2015-10-03</echo:PickupDate>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <echo:ShipmentType></echo:ShipmentType>
                  <echo:PalletQty>0</echo:PalletQty>
                  <echo:ReturnMultipleCarriers>false</echo:ReturnMultipleCarriers>
                  <echo:SaveQuote>false</echo:SaveQuote>
               </echo:Request>
            </echo:Requests>
         </echo:echoRateRequest>
      </echo:GetQuote>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Received response:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetQuoteResponse xmlns="http://www.echo.com/">
         <GetQuoteResult>
            <TotalRateQuotes>1</TotalRateQuotes>
            <RateQuote>
               <QuoteId>0</QuoteId>
               <Request>
                  <TotalWeight>1000</TotalWeight>
                  <Items>
                     <Item OriginId="1" DestinationId="1">
                        <Class>70</Class>
                        <Weight>1000</Weight>
                     </Item>
                  </Items>
                  <Accessorials>
                     <Accessorial>
                        <AccessorialId>12</AccessorialId>
                        <Charge>0</Charge>
                        <PickDel/>
                        <RateType/>
                        <Description>?</Description>
                     </Accessorial>
                  </Accessorials>
                  <Origin Id="">
                     <Name/>
                     <Address1/>
                     <Address2/>
                     <City/>
                     <State/>
                     <Zip>91101</Zip>
                  </Origin>
                  <Destination Id="?">
                     <Name/>
                     <Address1/>
                     <Address2/>
                     <City/>
                     <State/>
                     <Zip>60425</Zip>
                  </Destination>
                  <PickupDate>2015-10-03T00:00:00</PickupDate>
                  <ShipmentType/>
                  <PalletQty>0</PalletQty>
                  <ReturnMultipleCarriers>false</ReturnMultipleCarriers>
                  <SaveQuote>false</SaveQuote>
               </Request>
               <RateDetails/>
               <Messages>
                  <Status>-999</Status>
                  <Errors>
                     <Error xsi:type="xsd:string">Unexpected Error has occured.</Error>
                  </Errors>
                  <Warnings/>
               </Messages>
            </RateQuote>
         </GetQuoteResult>
      </GetQuoteResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I was really working hard on it and was unable to find solution on this issue. If you want you can test  using these links your self.

Standard (production):

http://services.echo.com/Quote.asmx

http://services.echo.com/Quote.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Have you happened to check the application log files and hope that will be some handy.

Comment: Have you gone pass thru it? Did you send right credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Tried from my end as well

Request:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap12:Body>
      <GetQuote xmlns="http://www.echo.com/">
         <echoRateRequest>
            <AuthInfo>
               <UserId>test-soap</UserId>
               <Password>xxxx</Password>
            </AuthInfo>
            <Requests>
               <Request>
                  <TotalWeight>3.12</TotalWeight>
                  <PickupDate>2002-09-24-06:00</PickupDate>
                  <PalletQty>12</PalletQty>
                  <ReturnMultipleCarriers>true</ReturnMultipleCarriers>
                  <SaveQuote>true</SaveQuote>
               </Request>
               <Request>
                  <TotalWeight>12.4</TotalWeight>
                  <PickupDate>2002-09-24-06:00</PickupDate>
                  <PalletQty>34</PalletQty>
                  <ReturnMultipleCarriers>true</ReturnMultipleCarriers>
                  <SaveQuote>true</SaveQuote>
               </Request>
            </Requests>
         </echoRateRequest>
      </GetQuote>
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Response I got

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetQuoteResponse xmlns="http://www.echo.com/">
         <GetQuoteResult>
            <TotalRateQuotes>1</TotalRateQuotes>
            <RateQuote>
               <QuoteId>0</QuoteId>
               <Request>
                  <TotalWeight>0</TotalWeight>
                  <Items/>
                  <Accessorials/>
                  <Origin/>
                  <Destination/>
                  <PickupDate>2002-09-24T01:00:00-05:00</PickupDate>
                  <PalletQty>12</PalletQty>
                  <ReturnMultipleCarriers>true</ReturnMultipleCarriers>
                  <SaveQuote>true</SaveQuote>
               </Request>
               <RateDetails/>
               <Messages>
                  <Status>-999</Status>
                  <Errors>
                     <Error xsi:type="xsd:string">Unexpected Error has occured.</Error>
                  </Errors>
                  <Warnings/>
               </Messages>
            </RateQuote>
         </GetQuoteResult>
      </GetQuoteResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It means there is a problem in the values we send , please check the logs in the servers what is causing this error ..  2nd look at the documentation what values each field must take . if we dont have proper input we always end with no happy response. the key here is to send proper values.

Comment: Suman, Thanks for the answere but I putting same values as mentioned in the documentation provided by third party but still getting same error.

Comment: link for the documentation please

Comment: Please check here: goo.gl/DZKz1x

Comment: it doent open.   I got this message.
We’re sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes. You can view the Apps Status Dashboard for the current status of the service.

If the issue persists, please visit the Gmail Help Center »

Try Again Sign Out


Show Detailed Technical Info

Comment: can you please tell me your gmail id so that I can forward it to you?

Comment: it is project and I got stuck!

Comment: Then there must be developers for this , ask them , mail them what is the proper request , As a QA you can ask them. unless proper request we are helpless here.

Comment: Problem solved, I had wrong user ID and password. Thanks for the help Suman